# Display total number of posts with a set additional numbers

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'm using blogger platform and this script to display the total number of posts:

```
<script style="text/javascript">function mbhTotalCount(json) {document.write(parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10));}</script><span class='count1'><script src="https://URL/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbhTotalCount"></script></span>
```

While this is working and displays the number of total posts, I would like to add "32" to the total number displayed by this code for certain reasons. Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done just by modifying the `mbhTotalCount` function and breaking the functionality into smaller chunks of what you were doing earlier. Something like:

```html
<script>
function mbhTotalCount(json) {
  var totalCount = parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t, 10);
  var newCountVal = totalCount + 32;
  document.write(newCountVal);
}
</script>
<span class='count1'>
  <script src="https://URL/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=mbhTotalCount"></script>
</span>
```